# progress dialog in asynctask getting eror

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

i am using a class the extand from Asynctask in the preexicute i call for progressdialog and in the postexicure i use dismiss. when i try to run the app the app keep collepsing.

```
public class DownloadText extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

   TextView tv;
   ImageView home,guest;
   Context context;
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public DownloadText(TextView tv,Context context) {
        this.tv=tv;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document document= null;
        Elements score;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(strings[1]).get();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         score=document.select(strings[0]);


        return score.text();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        tv.setText(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.example.aviv.project1.SummeyAct has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f838863 V.E......
>   R......D 0,0-1248,348} that was originally added here
>                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:469)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:309)
>                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:328)
>                        at com.example.aviv.project1.DownloadText.onPreExecute(DownloadText.java:46)
>                        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
>                        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
>                        at com.example.aviv.project1.BoxScoreFragment$2$1.run(BoxScoreFragment.java:107)
>                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
>                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768)

Comment: Does your activity still exist after the execution of this background task?

Comment: try to override the `onDestroy` method and add this in it                    
 `if(dialog != null) { dialog.dismiss(); dialog = null; }`

Comment: your code seems fine, I believe the context is destroyed before it can attach itself to your activity or gets destroyed in between

Comment: i didn't understand where i need to overade the onDestroy method

Comment: below that `onCancelled()` method finish bracket. Assuming you are using windows OS press `Ctrl + O` and select `override methods` and in that list select `onDestroy`

Comment: i don't have this function in my asynctask class